# How to use Post/SendMessage (User32.dll) to make Alt+Space combitation/event

Tags: c#, sendmessage, postmessage, user32

I need to make Post/SendMessage  that will make Alt+Space that will open some tab that i need in windows aplication.**I can't use SendKeys `SendKeys.Send("% ")`** i have to use Post/SendMessage only.

This what i have tried so far

```
 private const uint WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
 private const uint WM_KEYUP = 0x0101;
 private const uint WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x0104;
 private const uint WM_SYSKEYUP = 0x0105;
 private const int VK_MENU = 0x12;
 private const int VK_SPACE = 0x20;

 PostMessage(Main, WM_SYSKEYDOWN, VK_MENU, 0);//
 PostMessage(Main, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_SPACE, 0);
 Thread.Sleep(1000);
 PostMessage(Main, WM_KEYUP, VK_SPACE, 0);
 PostMessage(Main, WM_SYSKEYUP, VK_MENU, 0);
```

Now i can see that Alt is pressed because tabs get under-lined(first letter)(it's happened in 99% winapp's),but the combination of Alt+Space not happened,and i don't know why.

Any one know what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Your PostMessage declaration is wrong.  With the ALT-key down, the VK_SPACE keystroke is reported with WM_SYSKEYDOWN/UP instead.  Posting the VK_MENU key just fakes the state of the ALT key, it isn't actually down when the app checks the keyboard state with GetKeyState().  AttachThreadInput + SetKeyboardState is required to update the thread's keyboard state.  Do consider a UI Automation library instead.

Comment: I build thread that press the Alt,but i can't find the way how to SetKeyboardState to Alt Pressed, to avoid GetKeyState().